# Flask session lost after redirect - seems like browser doesn't set the cookie. What am I missing?

Tags: flask, session, redirect, session-cookies

I have a web app that makes a POST request to:

```
https://localhost:5000/processOneTapCredentials
```

This endpoint sets some data in flask.session, and then returns a redirect to another endpoint (`https://localhost:5000/login/success`). I can confirm it attempts to set the session. The response headers for the first endpoint (the 302 response) includes:

[image]

On the second endpoint, the session is empty though. I see that when the 302 is processed, there is no cookie header set in the headers:

So the flow is:

- Web app makes a XHR request (POST) to `https://localhost:5000/processOneTapCredentials`
- `https://localhost:5000/processOneTapCredentials` sets some flask.session info and returns a 302 to `https://localhost:5000/login/success`
- `https://localhost:5000/login/success` gets invoked (I see in dev tools), but there is no cookie, so session is empty.

I have set the Flask key correctly, and the session works between redirects in other situations (such as when Flask-dance redirects to authenticate a user). So I must be doing something wrong.

What am I missing?

Comment: The person who downvoted with no comment: which guidelines did this question not meet?

Comment: Did you found any solution? I have the same issue. In my case it only happens when I deploy my app on production with IIS and windows server using htpps redirection. In my development setup with no https there is no problem.

Answer (score -1):

make sure your `app['SECRET_KEY']` is not changing, and if you are redirecting to an external website or redirect from http to https you need to set your `SAMESITE` policy properly, with a `SAMESITE='Lax'` cookies are not forwarded, try setting it to `None` and see it the problem is related to your `SAMESITE` policy